# How to parse simple JSON

Tags: json, ajax, parsing

I am trying to parse my JSON file

```
{"data":[{"0":"9","c_id":"9","1":"Milan","c_name":"Milan","2":"2020-04-26 10:55:39","created":"2020-04-26 10:55:39","3":"2020-04-26 10:55:39","updated":"2020-04-26 10:55:39"}]}
```

with this code

```
    $('#button').click(function(){

var cityname = $("#cityname").val();


$.ajax({
  url: 'myurl.php?q='+cityname,
  dataType: "json",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(data) {
    show = "<h2>" + data.c_name + "</h2>";

    $.each(data.list, function(index, val) {

    });
    $("#showCity").html(show);

  }
});
});
```

to get c_name from it, but unsuccessfuly. Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is an array so , you need parse it using some loop or directly you can get data values using `data.data[0].c_name` .

**Demo Code** :

```js
//your response
var data = {
  "data": [{
    "0": "9",
    "c_id": "9",
    "1": "Milan",
    "c_name": "Milan",
    "2": "2020-04-26 10:55:39",
    "created": "2020-04-26 10:55:39",
    "3": "2020-04-26 10:55:39",
    "updated": "2020-04-26 10:55:39"
  }, {
    "0": "9",
    "c_id": "9",
    "1": "Milan1",
    "c_name": "Milan1",
    "2": "2020-04-26 10:55:39",
    "created": "2020-04-26 10:55:39",
    "3": "2020-04-26 10:55:39",
    "updated": "2020-04-26 10:55:39"
  }]
}
//to get individual key value
console.log(data.data[0].c_name)
console.log(data.data[1].c_name)
var show = "";
$.each(data.data, function(index, val) {
  show += "<h2>" + val.c_name + "</h2>";//append results in show variable
});
$("#showCity").html(show);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="showCity"></div>
```

Comment: if this answer helped you don't forget to mark this [answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)